# matching two csv columns (fuzzy?) and extracting row information

Tags: python, bash, csv

I have two csv files with some 1k entries each like so:

```
#1.csv
Org,Address,Phone
George, 121 faraday street, 837-837
Newton, 837 Bohr Street, 8327-837
...
```

```
#2.csv
Org,location,course
George William, Paris, Engineering
P Newton, London, Arts
...
```

Essentially, column 1 of 2.csv contains some slight variation (typos mostly) of names in column 1 of 1.csv.

I am looking to produce the output which looks like so (adding the corresponding location element from 2.csv into 1.csv):

```
#result.csv
Org,Address,Phone
George, 121 faraday street, 837-837, Paris
Newton, 837 Bohr Street, 8327-837, London
...
```

Ofcourse, the matching wont be perfect because it is could be fuzzy, but I was wondering whats the best way to go about this. Bash or python are both ok since the target system has these.

The idea I had was to run:

```
for i in entry:
    <match i to all entries on 2.csv>
    <get matching row>
    <add row to column>
```

But how can I accomplish this? since I am not sure whats the best way to match.

Comment: what (code) have you tried so far to implement the 'fuzzy' match? as currently written the question doesn't really meet SO requirements since we have no actual code to reference; instead this looks more like a brainstorming question on how to do a fuzzy match ... which will likely get this question closed as 'Not about programming'

Comment: hmm Is it fuzzy matching? I dont really know I thought it could be? Is there any bash tool I can use for this?

Comment: how would we know to *not* match `George Inc` to `P Newton Inc` ... because of the `Inc`?

Comment: I'm just re-using the words from the subject ... `matching` ... `fuzzy`; `'partial'` match? `'substring'` match? *shrug*

Comment: @markp-fuso yea its mostly like `string and substring` match. ie `partial match`. I could remove all `Incs` btw?

Comment: have you tried a web search on `bash fuzzy matching`? brings up a few hits that may be a good start ... like [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/753608) ... ?

Comment: removing the `Inc` wouldn't help since I'm assuming that may be part of your actual data; otherwise we could require you (re)edit the data until we're dealing with exact matches; as for the pseudo code in the latest edit ... that still doesn't meet SO's requirements as it's not actual code ... we're still being asked to come up with a methodology, design and code

Comment: @markp-fuso I have deleted the `Inc` as per your suggestion. I can delete that using grep. honestly, I am not asking you to come with with methodology, design and code lol literally just looking for pointers on how to best fuzzy match on the commandline and/or python.

Comment: AND what will you do if there are 2 `Georges`? (seems quite likely given 1k entries. Design your system to flag problem output. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: there wont be two of them since they have been filtered for duplicates!

Comment: *`filtered for duplicates`* could mean you end up with `George Jones`, `George Smith` and `Henry George` ... or maybe 2 lines with `George Jones` but with different addresses ... any of which highlights shellter's question

Comment: And *LLoyd George* and *George Harrison* (-:!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some have said, what is meant by [fuzzy](/questions/tagged/fuzzy) matching is (*pardon the pun*) fuzzy!

As long as the **surnames** in file1 are unique, meaning *only one line with any given surname*, this will give you what you want.

Assuming that the file1 has only the **surname**, and you are matching with a set of names that are not "**ambiguous**" in the file2 (*no cross-over of names used as both first or last*), then the logic implemented in this script will offer you a solution.

As some have stated, if you have surnames in file1 *which could match either surname or name in file2*, and you **don't** want that, then you have to **add logic to split the first field** of file2 and examine the desired element to match against the file1 surname.

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

file1="contact.csv"
cat >"${file1}" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
Org,Address,Phone
George, 121 faraday street, 837-837
Newton, 837 Bohr Street, 8327-837
Isayevich, #169 - Tverskaya 12, 878-979 
EnDoFiNpUt

file2="events.csv"
cat >"${file2}" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
Org,location,course
George William, Paris, Engineering
P Newton, London, Arts
Aleksandr Isayevich Solzhenitsyn, Troitse-Lykovo, Literature
EnDoFiNpUt    

### Desired Output
file3="eventContact.csv"
#Org,Address,Phone
#George, 121 faraday street, 837-837, Paris
#Newton, 837 Bohr Street, 8327-837, London

awk -v dbg=1 -v f1="${file1}" '\
BEGIN{
    split("", eventContact )
    indexE=0 ;
    while( getline < f1 ){
        indexE++ ;
        n=split($0, tmp, "," ) ;
        for( j=1 ; j <= n ; j++ ){
            eventContact[indexE,j]=tmp[j] ;
            if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\t|", indexE, j, eventContact[indexE,j] ; } ;
        } ;
    } ;
    split("", event) ;
    if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\t|-- End of initialization --\n" ; } ;
}
{
    if( NR > 1 ){
        split($0, event, "," ) ;
        if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\t|", event[1] ; } ;

        m=split(event[1], names ) ;

        nMatch=0 ;
        for( k=1 ; k <= m ; k++ ){
            for( i=2 ; i <= indexE ; i++ ){
                if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\t|\t", eventContact[i,1] ; } ;

                #if( index( event[1], eventContact[i,1] ) != 0 ){
                #if( eventContact[i,1] ~ event[1] ){
                if( names[k] ~ eventContact[i,1] ){
                    if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\t|\t\t", event[2] ; } ;
                    eventContact[i,4]=event[2] ;
                    nMatch=1 ;
                    break ;
                } ;
            } ;
            if( nMatch == 1 ){ break ; } ;
        } ;
    } ;
}
END{
    if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\t|-- End of match-making --\n" ; } ;
    eventContact[1,4]="Location" ;

    for( i=1 ; i <= indexE ; i++ ){
        printf("%s,%s,%s,%s\n", eventContact[i,1], eventContact[i,2], eventContact[i,3], eventContact[i,4] ) ;
    } ;
}' "${file2}"   #>"${file3}"
```

**Output (with dbg=1):**

```
    | 1 1 Org
    | 1 2 Address
    | 1 3 Phone
    | 2 1 George
    | 2 2  121 faraday street
    | 2 3  837-837
    | 3 1 Newton
    | 3 2  837 Bohr Street
    | 3 3  8327-837
    | 4 1 Isayevich
    | 4 2  #169 - Tverskaya 12
    | 4 3  878-979 
    |-- End of initialization --

    | George William
    |    George
    |         Paris
    | P Newton
    |    George
    |    Newton
    |    Isayevich
    |    George
    |    Newton
    |         London
    | Aleksandr Isayevich Solzhenitsyn
    |    George
    |    Newton
    |    Isayevich
    |    George
    |    Newton
    |    Isayevich
    |         Troitse-Lykovo
    |-- End of match-making --

Org,Address,Phone,Location
George, 121 faraday street, 837-837, Paris
Newton, 837 Bohr Street, 8327-837, London
Isayevich, #169 - Tverskaya 12, 878-979 , Troitse-Lykovo
```